# Can any one help me with some guidance to implement pinned headers / Sticky headers in scroll view using Nativescript

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I want to stick headers to the top during scroll like contacts scroll (sample video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eikTReAyXBc), i did some searching on the internet bout could not find anything concrete, experts using Nativescript kindly guild. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this question is off-topic here: it's a very broad topic (and possibly a tutorial/documentation recommendation question), and there are likely many ways to solve your particular challenge. Also, this requires someone to watch a video to understand what you're asking, and then relies 100% on the community to create a solution for you. Please edit your question to be specific, and also show what you've done, where you're stuck, expected vs actual output, errors, etc.